# Explain me a line of code. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

I opened one of the helpers page of **altered_beast** forum on github and saw this code:

```
  def recent_topic_activity(topic)
    return false unless logged_in?
    return topic.last_updated_at > ((session[:topics] ||= {})[topic.id] || last_active)
  end
```

Can you explain me the 3rd line in details.

- What is this  `">"` for.
- How this construction works: `(session[:topics] ||= {})[topic.id])`.

  I understand the first part of the line. If `session[:topics]` equals 0, then an empty hash assigns to it. But I've never seen anything like this  `()[topic.id]`

here's that page: [git](https://github.com/stiff/altered_beast/blob/master/app/helpers/forums_helper.rb)

Thanks in advance.
I'm new to ruby on rails but not a total noob.

Comment: The `>` is comparing two times: is the first after the second. If `topic.id` is 3, say, then you have `session[:topics][3]` if `session[:topics]` exists, or nil otherwise. Lastly, your question includes `()[topic.id]`. Maybe that is causing the confusion; look again, there is no `()`.

Comment: ()[topic.id] I was talking about this (session[:topics] ||= {})[topic.id]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets rewrite that 3rd line to be less terse.

```
# set topics hash to load from the session.
# If nothing in session, use an empty hash
topics_hash = session[:topics] || {}

# Look in the topics hash for a specific topic id.
# if nothing is found, use last_active (whatever that is)
topic_updated_at = topics_hash[topic.id] || last_active

# If the topics last_updated_at timestamp is greater than (meaning later in time)
# than the topic_updated_at we calculated above, return true. Otherwise false.
return topic.last_updated_at > topic_updated_at
```

Values in parentheses are evaluated first and then treated like a single value. Which means anywhere there is a variable name in the above code, you could replace it with the code that set that variable in parentheses. So these two lines:

```
topics_hash = session[:topics] || {}
topic_updated_at = topics_hash[topic.id] || last_active
```

Could become one line that does the exact same thing:

```
topic_updated_at = (session[:topics] || {})[topic.id] || last_active
```

You could, in theory, do that that kind of coding for a whole program, maximizing the complexity of every line. Some people love it.  In practice it makes it very hard to understand what's going on.

So the 3rd line is simply a clever compression of all these steps into a single expression. Perhaps too clever.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break it down:

```
topic.last_updated_at > something # this is a comparison therefore
# will return true or false
```

About `something`:

```
(session[:topics] ||= {})[topic.id] || last_active # this is an OR (||)
# expression, it will return either the first part if it is not nil or false
# otherwise it will return the second part (last_active)
```

the *first part* is:

```
(session[:topics] ||= {})[topic.id] # this is accessing a nested hash
# (session is a hash), with the key `topic.id`
#
# if session[:topics] exist, it must be a hash so this is like saying:
#   session[:topics][topic.id]
#
# if session[:topics] is nil, then it will be assigned an empty hash
# which will be accessed
```